# Numbers $n$ for which there cannot be exactly $n$ group elements of order $n$.

Tags: group-theory

*If this question has been asked before, then I'm sorry. I tried looking online and posted a chat message [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59870949#59870949) to no avail.*

### Motivation:

> **Lemma 1:** Each group has exactly $0$ elements of order $0$.

*Proof:* Trivial. $\square$

> **Lemma 2:** Each group has exactly one element of order one.

*Proof:* That element is clearly the identity. $\square$

> **Lemma 3:** No group has exactly two elements of order two.

*Proof:* Suppose $x$ and $y$ are the only elements of order two.

Suppose $xy=yx$. Then $(xy)^2=x(yx)y=x^2y^2=ee=e$. But if the order of $xy$ is two, then either $xy=x$, in which case $y=e,$ a contradiction, or $xy=y$, in which case $x=e$, another contradiction.

Therefore, $xy\neq yx$. Consider $xyx^{-1}$. We have

$$\begin{align}
(xyx^{-1})^2&=(xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1})\\
&=xy^2x^{-1}\\
&=xx^{-1}\\
&=e,
\end{align}$$

so that either $xyx^{-1}=e$, which implies $y=e$, a contradiction, or $xyx^{-1}$ has order two. But then either $xyx^{-1}=x$, in which case $x=y$, a contradiction, or $xyx^{-1}=y$, in which case $xy=yx$, another contradiction. $\square$

> **Lemma 4:** No group has exactly three elements of order three.

*Proof:* We have, for all $x$, that $\lvert x^{-1}\rvert=\lvert x\rvert$. But if there exist exactly three elements $a,b,c$ of order three, then the fact that none of them is its own inverse implies that, either, WLOG, $a^{-1}=b\neq c^{-1}=d$ for some $d$, which would have order three by the above, a contradiction, or each inverse is a new element of order three, another contradiction. $\square$

### The Question:

For which $n\in\Bbb N$ there cannot be exactly $n$ elements of order $n$ in any group${}^\dagger$?

### Thoughts:

I guess prime numbers are important here. I'm not sure why.

In $\Bbb Z_p$ for prime $p$, each nonidentity element has order $p$, and there are $p-1$ of them; that's close.

In $\Bbb Z$, there are countably infinitely many elements of order infinity. I had finite $n$ in mind though.

---

This question occurred to me upon learning **Lemma 4**. I knew about **Lemma 3**, so it seemed natural to ask.

It wouldn't surprise me if this has been investigated before.

I doubt I could answer it.

---

The technique of considering the case when the elements commute separately from when they don't, as in the proof of **Lemma 3**, seems unlikely to generalise to higher $n$; I'm not sure why I think this.

The fact that an element of order $n$ doesn't equal its inverse for $n\ge 3$ might help.

---

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: The group need not be finite.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3718530/104041)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There is no reason for a downvote (+1) Must the group be finite ?

Comment: Thank you, @Peter :)

Comment: The group doesn't have to be finite, @Peter.

Comment: What about $n=9$ ? I did not find an example in my old table with group element orders.

Comment: [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219245) can help.

Comment: @Peter Don't elements of order 9 come in pairwise disjoint sets of 6?

Comment: @Arthur Seems so, but can we prove that the number of elements must actually be a muitple of $6$ ?

Comment: @Peter Each element of order 9 generates a cyclic subgroup of order 9. This subgroup has six elements of order 9, and each of those generate the same subgroup. So elements of order 9 naturally partition themselves in sets of 6 that belong together by virtue of being mutual powers of one another.

Comment: @Arthur But (1) could there be a non-trivial interesction of such subgroups and (2) What about infinite groups ?

Comment: @Peter If two cyclic subgroups of order 9 have an order 9 element in common, then that order 9 element generates both groups, so the groups just be the same. What order 3 elements they may have in common is irrelevant. And infinite groups may have infinitely many of these 6-sets, but they each still must have exactly 6 elements and be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @Arthur Can we apply a similar argument for every prime power $n$ and every prime $n$ ?

Comment: @Peter Why limit yourself to prime powers? Cyclic groups exist of all orders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132624/discussion-between-peter-and-arthur).

Comment: @Peter No. I do not move to chat. There is much more pressure to respond immediately, and I don't get notified when someone responds to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $G$ be a group with exactly $n$ elements of order $n$. Then there exists $a \in G$ of order $n$. Now, the elements of $\{a, a^2, ... , a^{n-1}\}$ of order $n$ will be exactly the elements $a^k$ with $k$ coprime to $n$. Therefore, exactly $\phi(n)$ of these elements will have order $n$. (See [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)). If $\phi(n)$ divides $n$, then we can construct the group $G = \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$, where $m = n / \phi(n)$. It is simple to verify that this group has exactly $n$ elements of order $n$.

We claim that for $n$ such that $\phi(n)$ does not divide $n$, no such group exists. Suppose for contradiction that $G$ has exactly $n$ elements of order $n$ and $\phi(n)$ does not divide $n$. we can write $G = \left\langle a, S| a^{n}=1, R\right\rangle$, where $S \cup \{a\}$ is the generating set and $R \cup \{a^n = 1\}$ is the set of relations. If $S$ is empty, then we have at most $\phi(n) < n$ elements of order $n$, a contradiction. Hence, we can assume there exists some $b \in S$. If $b$ is of infinite order and does not commute with $a$, then there will be infinitely many elements of order $n$ given by $\{bab^{-1}, b^2 a b^{-2}, ... \}$, a contradiction. In the case that $b$ does commute with $a$, then we have not added any elements of order $n$ so we still have $\phi(n) < n$ elements  of order $n$, a contradiction. Hence, $b$ is of finite order, say $m$. If $b$ commutes with $a$, there will be $\phi(n) m$ elements of order $n$, but since we are assuming there are exactly $n$ elements of order $n$, (so $ \phi(n) m = n$), this contradicts the fact that $\phi(n)$ does not divide $n$. If $b$ does not commute with $a$, a similar argument (using conjugation) yields the same contradiction.

Therefore, there exists a group with exactly $n$ elements of order $n$ if and only if $\phi(n)$ divides $n$. This nicely includes the prime case we discussed, since $\phi(p) = p-1$ for all prime $p$.

Moreover, it seems like this can be generalized to show that there exists a group with exactly $k$ elements of order $n$ if and only if $\phi(n)$ divides $k$. A nice result!

Comment: Thank you. I see how this can be generalised for prime $n$; however, I don't see how to generalise to composite $n$: do you mean $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_n$?

Comment: Yes I have just noticed the same error. It may be that we need to consider the cases that $n \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and $n \equiv 2 \mod 4$...

Comment: Again, thank you, but I still don't understand how to generalise to other composite $n$.

Comment: one more error actually. It is not always the case that $\phi(n)$ divides $n$.

Comment: In any group $G$, the number of elements of order $n$ is $\phi(n) k$, where $k$ is the number of cyclic subgroups of order $n$. Hence if there are exactly $n$ elements of order $n$, then $\phi(n)$ divides $n$.